# Count one column if unique values in another column VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that I need to sum how many values "UDL" there is in column(N:N), but the problem is they should only be counted for every unique number in column (C.C)

So for every number that also has "UDL" in column N they should only be counted once as there can be a lot of duplicates.

Hope you can help :)

Comment: If you share some sample data it would be great :)

Comment: You can move the data from `col C` by simple copy and paste into a blank column and then use remove duplicates from that column you will have unique values in that column then you can just use those values and use a loop over column N to test `"UDL"` string equality test

Comment: Column C is a numberserie  like 218404 and this serie can have several duplicates. and column N has the values of like UDL-SPE or POS and the will have the same duplicates. I need somehow to see how many unique Col.C that has UDL in col N

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a loop & delimited string would be a quick way to get what you're wanting. Assuming Column A is always filled & has a header in row 1, something like:

```
Dim u as string
Dim i as long
dim t as long
i = 2

Do While Range("A" & i).value <> ""
    If Range("N" & i).value = "UDL" Then
        If InStr(1, u, "|" & Range("C" & i).value & "|") = 0 Then
            t = t + 1
            u = u & "|" & Range("C" & i).value & "|"
        End If 'else the value in C is non-unique
    End If 'else not UDL so no action needed
    i = i + 1
Loop

Range("A" & i + 1).value = t 'Outputs t to column A with a blank row between it & your data
```

That'll need some adjusting based on what column should control the loop, what row the loop should start on, and where you want the count to go.

Comment: Hello JMichael, cant get it to work but i think this is actually what im after. In sheet "956" i need to find how many unique values it is, if the column N is "UDL". The total value should then go into cell "B17" in sheet 1.

Comment: I'm happy to help you address whatever error(s) you're running into. Just give some details on what happens when you try to run the macro you wrote. Ideally you'll update your original question to include the macro code as well.